# Custom response headers with Strongloop framework

Tags: cors, strongloop

Whenever my Chrome browser makes a request to the REST api server a browser error appears in console saying `Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Range"`. Now I've managed to fix this in my vanilla express server (i.e. without StrongLoop) in two distinct ways:

- manually setting response headers `res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers")` *OR*
- using the *node-cors* `allowedHeaders` and `exposedHeaders` options (see https://github.com/TroyGoode/node-cors#configuration-options)

Now how can I achieve this in my StrongLoop instance? Official SL documentation only talks about `cors.origin` and `cors.credentials`, see http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/config.json.

Have I missed anything?

**UPDATE** with the best solution:

```
// config.json
"cors": {
  "origin": true,
  "credentials": true,
  "allowedHeaders": ["X-Requested-With"],
  "exposedHeaders": ["Content-Range"]
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [node-cors](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors) behind the scene. The cors options configured in config.json will be passed to node-cors. Can you try that?

Comment: I assume node-cros is about https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors, correct? In fact I'll suggest an edit for your answer.

Comment: it *did* work as you said, I'm sure I tried this before. I'll add the new source to my question, for others to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own middleware handler like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/loopbackjs/response$20header/loopbackjs/y7vB4RFDS0E/Xyb-J2oYQakJ

Or you can add a remote hook and manipulate the response header manually via the context object. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+hooks